# What is the first parameter in conn.set_listener() used for?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

Here's the code I'm looking at.

```
from stomp import *
c = Connection([('127.0.0.1', 62613)])
c.set_listener('print', PrintingListener())
c.start()
```

What is `'print'` in `c.set_listener('print', PrintingListener())` used for?

I checked some docs here https://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/stomp.html#module-stomp.listener

but was unable to find out.

Mostly I just want to be sure that passing in an empty string there or the same value for multiple listeners is okay.

Comment: `from stomp import *` is enough to tell me that this is a bad code example.

Comment: Presumably it is to set the output of the listener to `stdout` but I agree that the docs are unclear on this topic

Comment: There's an example using an empty string in the README, so it seems that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in `set_listener` is simply the *[name](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/master/stomp/connect.py#L26)* of the listener instance. You can use this same name later when invoking [`get_listener`](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/master/stomp/connect.py#L31) and [`remove_listener`](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/master/stomp/connect.py#L31) (which both take a `name` parameter). It's also useful if you want to set multiple listeners on a single connection (i.e. with different names). [The documentation](http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html#sending-and-receiving-messages) refers to this saying:

> Note that listeners can be named so you can use more that one type of listener at the same time

To be clear, an empty string (i.e. `''`) is a valid name just like any other string would be.